# How can I apply an xsl transform requiring a namespace without outputting the namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am Trying to produce the following XML output but when I run the transform below it includes the namespace, is there a way to change this behavior?

Desired Output:

```
<val>Running</val>
```

Current Output:

```
<val xmlns:x="http://www.mesa.org/xml/B2MML-V0600">Running</val>
```

SourceXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WorkPerformance xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.mesa.org/xml/B2MML-V0600">
<PublishedDate>2019-09-13T16:45:16.4042764+01:00</PublishedDate>
<WorkResponse>
    <JobResponse>
        <JobOrderID />
        <StartTime>2019-09-13T16:45:16.3762939+01:00</StartTime>
        <EquipmentActual>
            <EquipmentID>unaccounted</EquipmentID>
            <Description>0</Description>
            <EquipmentActualProperty>
                <ID>EquipmentState</ID>
                <Value>
                    <ValueString>Running</ValueString>
                    <Key />
                </Value>
            </EquipmentActualProperty>
        </EquipmentActual>
    </JobResponse>
</WorkResponse>
</WorkPerformance>
```

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.mesa.org/xml/B2MML-V0600">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"  method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <val><xsl:value-of select="//x:ValueString"/></val>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the solution is to add the following to the xsl:

```
exclude-result-prefixes="x"
```

so the full amended stylesheet is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:x="http://www.mesa.org/xml/B2MML-V0600"exclude-result-prefixes="x">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"  method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <val><xsl:value-of select="//x:ValueString"/></val>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```